# Array prototype works in chrome extension but gives TypeError in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox-addon-sdk

I found this helpful code snippet here on stackoverflow:

```
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
            this.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

I use it to remove empty values from arrays in a chrome extension that Im currently porting to firefox. I use ist like this:

```
foobar = foo.concat(bar).clean('').toString();
```

Which works fine in chrome, but in firefox I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: foo.concat(...).clean is not a function
```

Any suggestions what might be the problem?

//EDIT//

foo and bar are arrays, foo comes from a json which gets parsed like this:

```
var json = {property: 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g'};
json = json.property.split(',');
```

and bar from a textarea that gets parsed like this:

```
function digestTextField (string) {
    // takes string of format "a, b , c", trims spaces, converts to lower case
    var rawText = document.getElementById(string + 'Events').value,
        digestedText = rawText.split(','),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < digestedText.length; i += 1) {
        digestedText[i] = digestedText[i].toLowerCase()
                            .replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
    }
    return digestedText;
}
```

both are then saved to, and read from simpleStorage, before .clean('') is called.

Comment: what are foo and bar?I believe they would be arrays,  Can you state the initialization code of foo and bar?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code posted, maybe you add clean to prototype after calling it? The following works in a xul application:

```
function jsdump(str) {
  Components.classes['@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1']
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService)
            .logStringMessage(str);
}
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
            this.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return this;
};
var foo = {property: 'a,b'};
foo = foo.property.split(',');
var bar="5,6,,7,".split(",");

jsdump("Array has clean:"+Array.prototype.hasOwnProperty("clean"));
jsdump("is foo an array:"+(foo instanceof Array));
jsdump("is bar an array:"+(bar instanceof Array));
jsdump(foo.concat(bar).clean('').toString());
```

in defaults\preferences\prefs.js:

```
pref("browser.dom.window.dump.enabled", true);
pref("javascript.options.showInConsole", true);
pref("javascript.options.strict", true);
pref("nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache", true);
pref("nglayout.debug.disable_xul_fastload", true);
```

Starting the application with:

```
firefox --app application.ini -jsconsole
```